# How can I configure an AWS EKS autoscaler with Terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I'm using the AWS EKS provider (github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks ). I'm following along the tutorial with https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/aws/eks-intro

However this does not seem to have autoscaling enabled... It seems it's missing the `cluster-autoscaler` pod / daemon?

Is Terraform able to provision this functionality? Or do I need to set this up following a guide like: https://eksworkshop.com/scaling/deploy_ca/

Comment: I extremely recommend leveraging this: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks

Comment: That is what I'm using (what the tutorial uses)

Answer (score 6):

You can deploy Kubernetes resources using Terraform. There is both a Kubernetes provider and a Helm provider.

```
data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "authentication" {
  name = "${var.cluster_id}"
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  # Use the token generated by AWS iam authenticator to connect as the provider does not support exec auth
  # see: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/161
  host = "${var.cluster_endpoint}"

  cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(var.cluster_certificate_authority_data)}"
  token                  = "${data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.authentication.token}"
  load_config_file       = false
}

provider "helm" {
  install_tiller  = "true"
  tiller_image    = "gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.12.3"
}

resource "helm_release" "cluster_autoscaler" {
  name       = "cluster-autoscaler"
  repository = "stable"
  chart      = "cluster-autoscaler"
  namespace  = "kube-system"
  version    = "0.12.2"

  set {
    name  = "autoDiscovery.enabled"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "autoDiscovery.clusterName"
    value = "${var.cluster_name}"
  }

  set {
    name  = "cloudProvider"
    value = "aws"
  }

  set {
    name  = "awsRegion"
    value = "${data.aws_region.current_region.name}"
  }

  set {
    name  = "rbac.create"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "sslCertPath"
    value = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt"
  }
}
```

Comment: Fair enough, seems odd that it would be missing from the tutorial though. I'll give this a try!

Comment: The hashicorp tutorials are mostly focused on deploying EKS, not specifically on getting a fully up and running kubernetes cluster. The metrics-server is still incubating in the kubernetes project.

Comment: For some strange reason it's giving me this error:

```
 * helm_release.cluster_autoscaler: error installing: Post https://ABB06A6EE62F55C039BB284DD4BB2DB3.gr7.us-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/kube-system/deployments: dial tcp: lookup ABB06A6EE62F55C039BB284DD4BB2DB3.gr7.us-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com: no such host
```

But I don't recognize that endpoint at all? It's also not in the tfstate file.

Comment: Running into an error of `helm_release.cluster_autoscaler: context deadline exceeded` ... Not sure if related to https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-helm/issues/183

Comment: Hmm, I did not previously run into that issue.

Answer (score 1):

*This answer below is still not complete... But at least it gets me partially further...*

1.

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding add-on-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:default
helm install stable/cluster-autoscaler --name my-release --set "autoscalingGroups[0].name=demo,autoscalingGroups[0].maxSize=10,autoscalingGroups[0].minSize=1" --set rbac.create=true
```

And then manually fix the certificate path:

```
kubectl edit deployments my-release-aws-cluster-autoscaler
```

replace the following:

```
path: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

With

```
path: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

2.

In the AWS console, give `AdministratorAccess` policy to the `terraform-eks-demo-node` role.

3.

Update the `nodes` parameter with (`kubectl edit deployments my-release-aws-cluster-autoscaler`)

```
        - --nodes=1:10:terraform-eks-demo20190922124246790200000007
```